# Sintaxis 1=1 en WHERE de SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Qué 'significado' tiene esta sentencia SQL en el clausula WHERE?

```
SELECT * FROM cat_precios WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY PRE_ID
```

Específicamente: `WHERE 1=1`

La verdad nunca había visto algo así y no tengo idea de como funciona. ¿Podrían explicarme qué evalúa ahí?

Como nota, no hay ningún campo llamado 1

Comment: mira este post donde se ha tratado el tema [1=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149142/where-1-1-statement)

Comment: No digo que pueda ser el caso pero es usado muchas veces para `SQL Injection` debido a que siempre va a ser verdadero y por tanto va a devolver resultados. Lo pongo como comentario ya que no creo que sea una respuesta en sí sino una aclaración.

Comment: @Error404 Esto se usa generalmente para ejecutar cadenas de sql desde una aplicación. Como el where ya está incluido, solo hay que agregar  `and` u `or` a la condición nueva sin tener que consistir si existe el Where o no. Algunos ponen otros números o cualquier condición que sea verdadera.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

En el query significa si Verdadero, osea que esta de más porque siempre será true y es una condición aparentemente inútil en ese caso...

Pero normalmente se utiliza cuando vas a crear un `WHERE` donde no sabes las condiciones exactas, si no que se van armando al vuelo, así todas las demás condiciones que se agreguen siempre llevaran `AND`.

**Ejemplo:**

Tienes una pantalla con varias opciones de FILTRADO:

- Por nombre
- Por fecha
- Por id

y todas son opcionales, asi que tu query puede quedar:

```
select * from tabla where
```

Pero no sabes que opciones de filtrado tendra, pueden ser todas o ninguna o alguna, entonces se arma un query generico:

```
select * from tabla where 1 = 1
```

que funcione para todos los casos y segun las opciones se le añaden las condiciones:

```
 - and nombre = 'nombre'
 - and fecha = '2016-01-01'
 - and id = 10
```

entonces query se podría armar:

```
select * from tabla where 1 = 1 and id = 10
```

dejando las opciones de filtrado dinámicas, de otra forma no podríamos saber si la condición debe llevar `and` o no o si el `where` tendría que ir en la consulta.

Comment: Excelente explicación simplemente genial....!!

Comment: Tiene sentido tu explicación, me sigue dejando confundido la razón real de por qué está así. Es decir, tiene la sentencia order después del where.. :S

Comment: @KodiakMx tiene order porque probablemente no se incluyo ningun filtro. Es decir agregar una condicion verdadera para agregar o no filtros adicionales y para este caso no se agrego.

Answer (score 5):

Tengo la idea que es más que todo lo utilizan cuando no se conocen en tiempo de compilación la cantidad de condiciones que la consulta tendrá; sino que estas son generadas hasta en tiempo de ejecución. Cuando ya se tiene el `WHERE 1=1` solo se concatenan las demás condiciones a esta.

Es igual que `WHERE = 1` o `WHERE = true`.

Comment: Claro. Esto se usa generalmente para ejecutar cadenas de sql desde una aplicación. Como el `where`ya está incluido, solo hay que agregar `and` u `or` a la condición nueva sin tener que consistir si existe el  `Where` o no.

Answer (score 2):

la sentencia where sirve para filtrar las filas que se seleccionan (que se van a mostrar) del conjunto de datos, cuando pones where true como en este caso (ya que 1 = 1 tecnicamente daria true) quiere decir que no hay restricciones y todos los registros se mostraran es lo mismo que si la consulta fuera:

```
SELECT * FROM cat_precios ORDER BY PRE_ID
```

sin el where.

Tambien se usa para armar consultas donde se va agregar 0 o mas restricciones al where ya que where debe de tener al menos una condición.

Answer (score 0):

1. Similar a this
2. 1=1? Claro simplemente es una condición como programador cuyo resultado es booleano "True"

Answer (score 0):

Una solución alternativa es controlar la cadena de condiciones. Si está vacía se añade WHERE, si ya contiene algo se añade AND. Luego concatenamos esa cadena a nuestra sentencia sql. El resultado es un poco más limpio que WHERE 1 = 1 pero también requiere un poco más de trabajo :-)

dim sWhere as string = String.Empty

For each condition in conditions

If sWhere = String.Empty then

sWhere = "WHERE "

Else

sWhere = sWhere & " AND "

End If

sWhere = sWhere & condition.ToString

next condition

Comment: Ahí yo veo sintaxis de un lenguaje de programación y el OP solo pregunta por SQL

Answer (score 0):

Comparto el razonamiento lógico que ha hecho Cristina Carrasco, si esperas armar condicionales dinámicamente en tus consultas es sin duda una opción fácil de manejarlo. Sin embargo creo que eso puede afectar el comportamiento en caso de tener las tablas indexadas, aunque no estoy seguro de ello.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/403981)